# Push into S3 or Pull into S3 which is faster for a small file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ftp, aws-lambda

So I have a use case where I need to put files from on-prem FTP to S3.

The size of each file (XML) is  5KB max.
The no of files is 100 files per minutes.
No, the use case is such that as soon as files come at FTP location I need to put into S3 bucket immediately.

What could be the best way to achieve that.
Here are my option

1. Using AWS CLI at my FTP location.(push mechanism )
2. Using lambda (pull mechanism.
3. Writing java application to put the file into S3 from FTP.

Or is there anything built in that I can leverage in.

Basically, i need to put the file in S3 as soon as possible because UI is built on top of S3 and if the file does not arrive immediately I might be in trouble.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), or an API call if you wish to do it from application code.

It doesn't really make sense doing it via Lambda, because Lambda would need to somehow retrieve the file from FTP and then copy it to S3 (so it is doing double work).

You can certainly write a Java application to do it, or simply call the AWS CLI (written in Python) since it will work out-of-the-box.

You could either use `aws s3 sync` to copy all new/updated files, or copy specific files with `aws s3 cp`. If you have so many files, it's probably best to specify the files otherwise it will waste time scanning many historical files that don't need to be copied.

The ultimate best case would be for the files to be sent to S3 directly, without involving FTP at all!

Comment: Thanks for the Info ...So for last point as you said files to sent S3 directly ...How can we do that ?For example i am generating xml files in my app server can i send it directly from there itself without using FTP?

Comment: Most definitely! Your app should call S3 directly and `PutObject` into S3. You will need to use an [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#sdk) for your preferred programming language. Everything on AWS can work via an API call from an SDK.